# Почему компилятор выдает предупреждение

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Я работаю в qt5. Добавил Dialog Button Box на форму и в ее слоте имею такой код:

```
void addFunction::on_buttonBox_clicked(QAbstractButton *button)
{
    switch ( ui->buttonBox->standardButton(button) )
    {
    case QDialogButtonBox::Ok :
        qDebug() << "pressed OK";
        break;
    case QDialogButtonBox::Cancel :
        qDebug() << "pressed Cancel";
        break;
    }
}
```

Я тестировал этот код и он работает нормально. Но почему компилятор выдает 19 предупреждений?

```
F:\Framework2\Framework\addfunction.cpp:58: предупреждение: enumeration value 'Yes' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
F:\Framework2\Framework\addfunction.cpp:58: предупреждение: enumeration value 'YesToAll' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
```

и так далее.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну предупреждение ведь довольно ясное: в `switch` Вы добавили не все случаи. Можете либо отключить это предупреждение(не рекомендуется), либо добавить `default` ветку в `switch`. Это должно успокоить компилятор.